# Does integrals in haskell include negative numbers?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, does the data type Integral type include negatives?

Comment: Integral is not a data type in Haskell. It is a class of types, some of which are signed (`Int`, `Integer`, etc.) and some of which are unsigned (`Word`, `Word64`, etc.).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Prelude> :i Integral
instance Integral Int
Prelude> (-5) :: Int
-5
```

Also yes.  But notice Integral isn't a data type but a class of types that may or may not include negatives.

Answer (score 7):

As others have said, `Integral` is not a type, but a class. There are *several* integral types.

The main types are `Int` (machine-precision) and `Integer` (unlimited precision), both of which support negative numbers.

There are also the types `Int8`, `Int16`, `Int32` and `Int64` which have a specific number of bits, and also support negative numbers. And then there is `Word8`, `Word16`, `Word32` and `Word64` which do *not* have negative numbers. (Hey, I didn't invent the naming!)